# What is the best way to schedule a view render as a task in django-chronograph or similar?

Tags: django, caching, view

The use case is I want to statically render a view daily.  It seems like there should be a pretty standard way to take a view/template and render static contents daily without simply saying "write a custom admin command" or a relatively simple command template that populates a static file.

The reason is to remove a large volume of database queries to make a site lightening quick, even on a lightweight vps by only touching the database daily instead of on every page view.

If there's a better way to do it, I'm open to that.  It just seems like the best way to do it is rendering static views on a regular basis and cache-ing the crap out of it before it even touches django.

Comment: this looks worth a shot, but i'm still open to suggestions https://github.com/pcraciunoiu/django-nginx-memcache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways I know to solve this:
1. You can use [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) (as described in [this](http://blog.disqus.com/post/62187806135/scaling-django-to-8-billion-page-views?goback=.gde_50788_member_5794178014073872385#!) blog post). Yet this solution takes a bit more time to get into because it's side technology you'll have to deal with. Also it takes more efforts to maintain it.
2. More "django-side" solution is to use django-celery for daily rendering your view and storing it in cache. You can move all your static view logic into task and render it there once a day. In your view you can just get rendered response from cache and return it to user.
3. Also you can use django [per-view cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache) and create task in celery to clear cache daily.

Comment: Thanks.  I wound up using nginx+memcache, but your answer got me looking at it as a cache config instead of trying to run some "gen-static" view and setting up urls to static files.